# How can I tell DD-WRT DHCP to assign same IP to the same device?

Tags: dhcp, dd-wrt

I installed DD-WRT mini image on my router. I have a board that gets rebooted a lot(development device). It is very frustrating that my board keeps getting different addresses every couple of reboots.

The network consists of my workstation, the router, and the development board. The board uses busybox udhcpc and ifupdown. I did not find any host specific settings in the web GUI.

Comment: Comment since I don't know the UI: Find a place in the UI where you can make assignments based on MAC address. The base firmware for Linksys (ahem, Cisco) devices has a page where they show the MAC addresses of the devices currently connected to the router, and you can force a long term mapping.  Im sure DD-WRT has the same, I just never have used it so can not be specific.

Comment: For some reason, I could not find it in the UI, that's why I was asking the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @RickHomolka suggests:

- You simply need to grab the MAC address of your development board network interface (either wireless or wired).

  - The easiest way to find this would be to check your DHCP lease table in DD-WRT
- Create a DHCP reservation in DD-WRT based on that MAC address

  - If possible, assign an IP address that is in the subnet but out of the current DHCP pool of addresses.

Here's the writeup from dd-wrt on [Static DHCP](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Static_DHCP)

[image]

Comment: Most router firmware should be able to show the MAC as the router sees it. IT would be easier to check the router UI first, then if it isn't shown there, then you can check your client (the board in this case).

Comment: Good call. Added that